# Matlab Error: Undefined function 'knnclassify' for input arguments of type 'double'

Tags: matlab, knn

I am trying to do `knnclassify` on `test_data(10000X784)`, `train_data(50000X784)`, `train_label(50000X1)` and `k = 1`

And I am calling this function as follows:

```
label = knnclassify(test_data,train_data,train_label,k);
```

Background:
Where `train_label` is numeric equivalent digit of the data given in `train_data`. I want to classify my `test_data`. The data in both the train and test are in random order, but the `train_label` totally corresponds with the data in the `train_data`.

In my friend's workstation it works fine, but in my laptop it gives this error:

```
    Undefined function 'knnclassify' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

What could be the reason for the issue and how to solve it? Do I need to install any package? If yes how?

Comment: Do you have the [bioinformatics toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/index.html)? Type [`ver`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ver.html) in the command line to find out.

Comment: Doesn't look like. I have Computer Vision System Toolbox, Image Processing Toolbox, Signal Processing Toolbox. How to install that?

Comment: [Check this description](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101885-how-do-i-install-additional-toolboxes-into-an-existing-installation-of-matlab)

Answer (score 2):

This error means that the function cannot be found in matlab, so you might missing the required toolbox. Just as @schorsch said you need to install the Bioinformatics toolbox.

A way to find out if the function is available in Matlab is typing `which knnclassify`. The output will be the route where the function resides or `'knnclassify' not found.` otherwise.